# Multi-Mobile Device Application Architecture

Tags: iphone, android, ipad, windows-phone-7, mobile

I'm considering building an application for Windows Phone 7, Android, iphone, ipad, and potentially more.  Since i'm going to be leveraging a similar look and feel and content, it seems to me like it might be worthwhile to try to create a common base structure that I could reuse across environments.

For instance, i could define the structure of the UI using XML or something, or utilize some common construction of the application which I could build a translator to gen the code in other environments, or even something else.  I'm in the very, very beginning stages of thought, and was wondering if anyone has tried this and come up with a good approach?  Any ideas?

Thanks.

Comment: Jack of all trades, master of none.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are some x-platform kits: [appcelerator](http://www.appcelerator.com/), [phonegap](http://www.phonegap.com/), etc. Or you could go the hybrid route and use something like mono as a half measure, then there is the possibility of building a web app with html5.

I wouldn't try to roll my own, that's for sure

Answer (score 3):

Beyond simple applications, it not going to happen.

The are a number of problems you will face like:

- Different native programming languages on different mobile platforms.
- Different UI paradigms on the different mobile platforms.
- Very different screen sizes even on the same mobile platform (e.g. iphone vs ipad).
- UI Localisation

To really take advantage of each mobile platform, you need to build the UI for that platform to maximise it's UI paradigm.  It also matters what screen sizes you want to support, catering for small screen sizes can hamstring you in what you can display in the UI unless you build different screen layout for different screen sizes to give a better UI experience (a lot of work).  This can be a big problem on one platform let alone expanding it to other platforms.

For the platforms listed, you can try using mono, but that will only help in the following ways:

- One programming language (C#) instead of a different language per platform.
- Application engine logic can be shared between platforms.
- Native UI per application.

The cons of using mono would be:

- You still need to write the UI layer per platform as mono binds to the underlying UI api.
- Mono runtime overhead in size and sometimes speed.
- Mono on the mobile platforms are still new, I have developed one iphone application in monotouch and I found lots of first-release type problems with it.

If you don't mind some of the con's then mono can be a great platform for developing certain levels of applications.

I have found that trying to define a master UI layout just doesn't work in all situations in any application that gets to complex in the information it needs to display to the user.  No matter how "complex" you can define the layout, something will break it.  You either have to live with a "bad" UI in some cases or have a maintenance overhead.

I like to develop an application for the mobile platform to try can get the most out of that platform and it's features.  This may mean that other platform versions of the app may work differently but at least it will feel correct on that platform.

Answer (score 0):

Be careful when translating iPad to Android designs.  Hopefully this article can help you out:

http://morriscodes.blogspot.com/2012/09/designing-for-android-tablets-vs-ipad.html